# Decomposition of Homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism, automorphism-group, semidirect-product

Is it correct that if $\psi \ : G \rtimes_{\phi_1} H \to G \rtimes_{\phi_2} H$, then $\exists f \in Aut(G)\ and \ g \in Aut(H)$, such that $\psi(G \rtimes_{\phi_1} H) \cong f(G) \times g(H)$

What about when $\psi$ is $\in Aut(G \rtimes H)$?

Comment: No, it's not true. If it were, then all automorphisms of $C_2\times C_2$ would be trivial.

Comment: Not sure what "$\psi\in G\rtimes H$" means (it is nonsense on its face). If you mean "is an inner automorphism", still no. For instance, $S_3$ viewed as $C_3\rtimes C_2$.

Comment: By "$\psi$ is $\in G \rtimes H$", did you mean "$\psi$ $\in Aut(G \rtimes H)$" ?

Comment: Oh yes you are correct. Sorry for the confusion. I have edited it.

Comment: The first question then is trivially "no", since you can take any nonsurjective endomorphism: it cannot possibly be given in the form $f(G)\times g(H)$, because then it would be surjective.